# How to set the cusror mark when we stayed what being typed on orientation changed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-edittext, android-xml

I have the EditText and some sentences have been wriiten after that when I changed the orientation then Cursor mark is started from the beginning ?

```
<EditText 
                    android:id="@+id/edt_address"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_text"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:maxLength="256"
                    style="@style/Text.Medium" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<EditText 
     ... 
     android:freezesText="true" />
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Mmm, it says it saves state to an icicle here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText So i guess you have to also restore it manualy. Is your editText inside a fragment?